# Django, Filter a list with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, database, object

I am trying to build filter that filters through a list when clicked (option values). I know that there are other questions similar to this, but I just can't seem to get the hang of it.

views.py

```
def gps_list(request):
    selected_programme = request.GET.get("selected_programme", None)

    gps = GoodPractice.objects.filter(
       id__in=ProgrammeList.objects.filter(programme__exact=selected_programme))
    print(gps)

    data = serializers.serialize("json", gps)
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

This is my script

```
<script>
    $("#programme").change(function () {
      event.preventDefault();
          var selected_programme = $(this).val();
          console.log(selected_programme);
      $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "gps_list" %}',
        data: {
          "selected_programme": selected_programme,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
          },
          error: function(response) {
            alert("oh no!");
          }
      });
    });
</script>
```

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Select programme type:</legend>
              <label for="programme">Programme type: *<abbr title="required"></abbr></label>

              <form action="{% url 'gps' %}" method="get">
              <select class="form-control" id="programme" name="progr" size="6" multiple>
                {% for programme in progr %}
                  <option  value={{programme.id}} {% if programme.id in progr_selected %}selected{% endif %}>{{programme.name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>

  {% autoescape off %}
  {% for gp in gps %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2 class="my-4">{{gp.name}}
        <small>{{gp.country}}</small>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title">{{gp.programme_type}}</h2>
          <p class="card-text">{{gp.what}}</p>
          <a href="{% url 'gps' %}/{{gp.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </fieldset>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endautoescape %}
</div>
```

So, what I need to is to find a way to filter `{{gp.name}}`, `{{gp.country}}`
`{{gp.programme_type}}` & `{{gp.what}}`.

Currently the `print(gps)` works correctly. 
Having `alert(response)` shows data, but when I use `alert(response.data)` I receive `undefined`.

Comment: You've added the AJAX code already. What's going wrong?

Comment: The AJAX call doesn't get linked to the btn and also I'm pretty sure that I'd need to implement AJAX to views.py as well since it's not that currently.

Comment: But I don't know how to do that and I've been searching for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `fetchDataAndDisplay` function is not being called is because you have added the click event listener to an element with the **id** of "btn-primary", but the button has the **class** of "btn-primary".

```
// Change the "#btn-primary" to ".btn-primary"
$(".btn-primary").click(function() {
    fetchDataAndDisplay();
});
```

You should be careful though as all buttons with the "btn-primary" class will trigger this action. I would advise using an id that is relavent to the action of the button like "gps-form-submit" for the button rather than a class.

Also you can pass the `fetchDataAndDisplay` function directly as the callback in your click event listener like so `$("#btn-primary").click(fetchDataAndDisplay)`.

As for what will actually handle your AJAX call you will need to make a separate view that returns an [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) object from Django or a [`Response`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#response) object from [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

There are few other issues with your code; this section of you markup makes no sense:

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit selections</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

You have opened two new divs around the form's closing tag without the opening tag being inside it's nearest parent. Something like this would make more sense:

```
  <form>

      <!-- rest of code -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit selections</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

For this section I'd recommend looking into using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
str += '<div class="item-details">' + 
       'User Id is = ' + data[i].userId + '<br />' +
       'Id is= ' + data[i].id + '<br />' +
       'Title is = ' + data[i].title + '<br />' +
       '</div>';
```

It would look something like this:

```
str += `<div class="item-details">
            User Id is = ${data[i]}<br />
            Id is = ${data[i].id}<br />
            Title is = ${data[i].title}<br />
        </div>`
```

This is easier to read and removes the need for loads of string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that I need to do if you check out views.py and .values (for example. "name", "country",) I need to get the AJAX call to filter those values. How should I do this?

Comment: So just to clarify, do you want the response to change based on the selected option in the `<select ... id="programme">` input?

Comment: Yeah, that's it.